# Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection.finishComposingText()' on a null object reference- Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

when i click on toolbar back button (as shown in gif) then error occurred : `Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection.finishComposingText()' on a null object reference`. I Think this is due to focus on EditText

[image]

======================================================================

[image]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection.finishComposingText()' on a null object reference
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:362)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

07-20 18:53:58.839 976-13033/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
    ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
07-20 18:53:59.239 3996-13041/? E/SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on crash_info_summary(package_name_touched)
07-20 18:53:59.569 976-1519/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with your code.
Try cleaning your build cache. see the image below
[image]

then rebuild your project

You should also try deleting .gradle folder in your project directory.